# php session variable not working between different pages

Tags: lamp, php

I created a simple login page in php with sessions and it was working great on my LAMP. But today I accidentally changed permission of my /var directory to something like chmod 777 /var, Although I changed back its permission to chmod 755 /var . But now when I tried to access my login page again, I was not able to login. On going through code again, I found that my SESSION variable is not retaining its data while transferring to different page. I am using session_start() in every page (on top of page) , moreover I checked session_id() , it is same in every page. I am using Apache and Mysql in linux environment (Ubuntu 12.04). Code of my program :

index2.php :

```
<?php 
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) 
{
header('Location: securepage.php');
}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Secure LOGIN</title>
</head> 
<body>
    <h2>User Login </h2>
    <form method="POST" action="login.php">
        <br>UserName : <input type= "text" name="username">
        <br>Password : <input type="password" name="password">
        <br><input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

login.php :

```
<?php
session_start();
include('load.php');
$obj = new load();
$conn = $obj-> connect();

if(!conn)
{
exit('Connection cannot be established');

}

mysqli_select_db($conn,'login') or die('Cannot be established');
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname='".$_POST['username']."' and pass =  '".md5($_POST['password'])."';";

$login = mysqli_query($conn,$query);


if(mysqli_num_rows($login) == 1)
{
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
 header('Location: securepage.php');
}
else
{
header('Location: index2.php');
}

?>
```

securepage.php :

```
<?php

session_start();


if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
header('Location: index2.php');
}

?>
<html>

<head>
<title>Secured Page</title>
</head>

<body>

<p>This is secured page with session: <b><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></b>
<br>You can put your restricted information here.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

On **echo $_SESSION['username']**, after if(mysqli_num_rows) statement in login.php it is correctly displaying the value of **username** , however on **print_r($_SESSION)** in securepage.php , it is showing an empty array.
This code was working great till yesterday , I don't know why it is not working now.
I even created two simple test pages to check my SESSION variable , but even that is not working. Although value in $_SESSION is set , but it is not transferring to second page. I have not touched any configuration settings of my LAMP.

[My phpinfo() screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0crzg.png)

[Permissions of var direcroty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJnHd.png)

Please tell me where I am going wrong.

Content of my **error.log**:

```
PHP Warning:  session_start(): open(/var/lib/php5/sess_mm4ja22k9n0r4gv512imc07ur0, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /var/www/public/index2.php on line 2, referer: http://localhost/index2.php

PHP Warning:  Unknown: open(/var/lib/php5/sess_mm4ja22k9n0r4gv512imc07ur0, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0, referer: http://localhost/index2.php

PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php5) in Unknown on line 0, referer: http://localhost/index2.php
```

Comment: did you check error.log of your web-server (apache/nginx)?

Comment: Updated the content of my error.log. Seems like some sort of permission problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentionned that your did `chmod 777` then back `755` to the `/var` directory (maybe even the subdirectories). Your problem started after that so it seems like a permission problem.

The `/var` directory contains the `www/` folder containing your web documents, but other folders as well ( `log`, `tmp`, etc.) as seen on your screenshot. 
Do you know where does your php configuration (php.ini) saves your php session files ?
Check out the [session.save_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) line just to be sure.

The default is `/tmp` but maybe you're using the `/var/tmp` or `/var/lib/php5`. The thing is, the `/var/tmp` folder is `chmod 777` by default so you sould revert back to that.

Good luck !

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
On changing the permission of my /var/lib , it is working fine now. However I landed into another problem , on sudo it displays :

    sudo: /var/lib/sudo writable by non-owner (040775), should be mode 0700

Comment: The problem is you're applying too wide permissions... You should have done `chmod 777 -R /var/lib/php5` and not on the whole `/var/lib` directory...

Comment: Changed the permission of the /var/lib/sudo to 0755
Everything working fine now !

Answer (score 0):

This is only a suggestion, as I'm not sure what's causing the problem. I'd made a similar permissions-related error which led to all my scripts failing to work properly, without any errors being logged in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. I did the following to solve the problem:

(in the terminal)

```
:$ chmod 775 -R /var/www
:$ chown <user-name>:www-data -R /var/www
```

Note that you'd have to prepend `sudo` if you are not the `root` user.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Smit for you useful suggestion. Figured out that my **/var/lib** did not had group permission to write. Solved the problem using :

**sudo chmod 775 -R /var/lib**

Thank you